# Linear dependence of two complex vectors and Euler's formula.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $x,y\in \mathbb{C}^n$ and $\vert\vert x\vert\vert_2=\vert\vert 
 y\vert\vert_2.$ Then $x$ and $y$ are linear independent if and only if
$y\neq x e^{i\theta}$ for some real $\theta$. Is this claim true?

I know $y=x e^{i\theta}\implies x\perp y$ because for example
$$
det
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & e^{i\theta}x_1\\
x_2 & e^{i\theta}x_2
\end{pmatrix}=0
$$
For the other direction, I tried using the definition of $x^*y=0$ and didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x = e^{i\theta}y$, then
$$
x+(-e^{i\theta})y = e^{i\theta}y +(-e^{i\theta})y = (e^{i\theta} - e^{i\theta})y = 0y = \vec{0}, 
$$
i.e., $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent.

Conversely, if $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent, then there are complex numbers $\lambda$ and $\mu$, at least one of which is nonzero, such that $\lambda x + \mu y =0$.

If $\mu =0$, then $\lambda x = 0 \implies x = 0$. But $\vert\vert x\vert\vert_2=\vert\vert y\vert\vert_2$, so $y = 0$. Thus, $x = e^{i\theta}y$ holds for any $\theta$. A similar argument applies when $\lambda =0$.

If $\lambda, \mu \ne 0$, then $x = \frac{\mu}{\lambda}y$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: So $\vert\vert x\vert\vert_2=\vert\vert y\vert\vert_2 \implies \vert\vert\frac{\mu}{\lambda}\vert\vert_2=1$?

Comment: Not quite: $\vert\vert x \vert\vert_2 = \vert\vert y \vert\vert_2 \implies \left\vert \frac{\mu}{\lambda}\right\vert = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**First direction**

*Lemma:*
$x$ is lin. ind. of $y \implies y \neq xe^{i\theta}, \forall \theta \in \Bbb R$

*Proof:*
By definition of linear independence, $\not\exists \lambda \in \Bbb C$ such that $y = \lambda x$ where $\lambda \neq 0$.  Let $\lambda = e^{i\theta}$.  If they are linearly independent, this cannot be.

**Other direction (by contrapositive)**

*Lemma:*
$y \neq xe^{i\theta}, \forall \theta \in \Bbb R \implies x$ is lin. ind. of $y$

*Proof:*
Suppose $x$ and $y$ are not lin. ind.

$\implies \exists \lambda \in \Bbb C$  s.t. $y = \lambda x$ and $\lambda \neq 0$

$\implies \left\lVert \lambda x \right\rVert = \left\lVert y  \right\rVert$
$\implies$
$ |\lambda| \cdot \left\lVert x \right\rVert = \left\lVert y \right\rVert$

If $\left\lVert x \right\rVert = \left\lVert y \right\rVert$, then $|\lambda| = 1 \implies \lambda = e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta \in \Bbb R$

Therefore, $\exists \theta \in \Bbb R$ s.t. $y = xe^{i\theta}$

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you Jack. I've fixed the question by adding the missing condition. The norms of $x$ and $y$ are the same.

Comment: The other direction is actually trivial.  By definition of linear independence, $\not\exists \lambda \in \Bbb C$ such that $y = \lambda x$.  Let $\lambda = e^{i\theta}$.  If they are linearly independent, this cannot be.

However, what is left to show is $y \neq xe^{i\theta} \implies$ x and y are linearly indepdendent.